# how to handle multiple request keys with the same value?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, model

For this project, I'm building out models and passing in values from the body of a POST request. I want to understand how I should be declaring the models.

Sample of JSON which I want to be posted to MongoDB.

```
{
    "signageId": "5cd857c4965f863b7c88d24a",
    "parameters": {
        "imageURL": "url.com",
        "page": {
            "pageHeight": "100", //want to change to "height"
            "pageWidth": "100"   //want to change to "width"
        },
        "density": {
            "height": "300",
            "width": "300"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to name pageHeight and pageWidth just "height" and "width" within the JSON, like I have done for the density segment, but I'm having difficulties knowing how to declare the models and grab the values from the request.

Model I'm using:

```
const ObjectSchema = new Schema({
    signageId: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
    parameters: {
        imageURL: {
            type: String,
            require: true
            }
        },
        page: {
            pageHeight: {
                type: String
            },
            pageWidth: {
                type: String
            }
        },
        density: {
            height: {
                type: String
            },
            width: {
                type: String
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Post router

```
router.post('/', (req, res) =>{
    const object = new Objects({
        signageId: req.body.signageId,
        imageURL: req.body.imageURL,
        page: req.body.page,
        pageHeight: req.body.pageHeight,
        pageWidth: req.body.pageWidth,
        density: req.body.density,
        height: req.body.height,
        width: req.body.width
    });
    try {
        object.save();
        res.json({object});
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new object should be something like this.

```
    const newObject = new Objects({
        signageId: req.body.signageId,
        parameters: {
            imageURL: req.body.imageURL,
            page: {
                height: req.body.pageHeight,
                width: req.body.pageWidth,
            },
            density: {
                height: req.body.height,
                width: req.body.width,
            }
        }

    });
```

**Notes**: 
1. Give your mongoose schema another name, in order to avoid javascript conflicts.
2. You can use `height` and `width` properties for different objects.

```
page: {
    height: {
        type: String
    },
    width: {
        type: String
    }
},
density: {
    height: {
        type: String
    },
    width: {
         type: String
    }
}
```

3. the model properties should be `required`, not require